# Capistrano 3. Wrong path in the shared_path variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, unicorn, capistrano3

I'am trying to create the Unicorn restart task with Capistrano 3:

Firstly, I set *unicorn_pid* variable:

`set :unicorn_pid, "#{shared_path}/tmp/pids/unicorn.pid"`

Then I pass it to the restart task:

```
  desc 'Restart application'
  task :restart do
    on roles(:app), in: :sequence, wait: 5 do
      execute :kill, "-USR2 `cat #{fetch(:unicorn_pid)}`" if test "[ -f #{fetch(:unicorn_pid)} ]"
      within release_path do
        execute :bundle, "exec unicorn -D -c config/unicorn.rb -E #{fetch(:stage)}"
      end
    end
  end
```

but when i run `cap production deploy:restart` i see:

```
DEBUG [f4159760] Running /usr/bin/env [ -f /var/www/shared/tmp/pids/unicorn.pid ] on dev.project.net
DEBUG [f4159760] Command: [ -f /var/www/shared/tmp/pids/unicorn.pid ]
```

So, instead `/home/user/project/shared/` path, #{shared_path} transform to `/var/www/shared/`

But when I specify this path directly in the task, without unicorn_pid variable I see in the output:

```
 INFO [567856e3] Running /usr/bin/env kill -USR2 `cat /home/user/project/shared/tmp/pids/unicorn.pid` on dev.educapsule.net
DEBUG [567856e3] Command: /usr/bin/env kill -USR2 `cat /home/user/project/shared/tmp/pids/unicorn.pid`
```

Why the path is changed to `/var/www/shared/` when I pass it in "custom" variable?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the problem is that when you call this:

```
set :unicorn_pid, "#{shared_path}/tmp/pids/unicorn.pid"
```

It's being evaluated the moment that line is processed, taking the as-then-current value of `shared_path` which is `/var/www/shared`.

Try changing that line to this which should delay it's execution until you actually reference `unicorn_pid`.

```
set :unicorn_pid, -> {"#{shared_path}/tmp/pids/unicorn.pid"}
```

Comment: I've specified `set :unicorn_pid, -> {"#{shared_path}/tmp/pids/unicorn.pid"}` and it works. Thanks.

Comment: Actually shared_path is not var in capistrano 3, it is DSL method. So proposed solution is not right, `fetch :shared_path` will return nil. Author's comment is right.
See [source](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/blob/aeab6b6a1e5c5e654f35321dcd7438a0659864d0/lib/capistrano/dsl/paths.rb#L60)

Comment: So @philip-hallstrom, please edit you answer, or I we will remove that and post correct one.